# A problem regarding the natural map $k[X]\to k[X,Y]/\langle F \rangle$.

Tags: modules, problem-solving, intuition, algebraic-curves

I am reading Fulton's book on algebraic curves.In section $2.1$ viz. *coordinate-ring* ,there is a problem which is given below:

> Assume $k$ is algebraically closed.Let $F\in k[X,Y]$ be  irreducible and monic in $Y$ i.e. $F=Y^n+a_1(X)Y^{n-1}+\dots+a_n(X)$ and $n>0$.Suppose $V=Z(F)\subset \mathbb A^2(k)$.Then the natural map $\varphi:k[X]\to k[X,Y]/\langle F\rangle=\Gamma(V)$ is one-one(so that $k[X]$ can be regarded as a subring of $\Gamma(V)$ ) and show that $\overline{1},\overline{Y},...,\overline{Y}^{n-1}$ generate $\Gamma(V)$ as a $k[X]$-module.

I need some hint in order to solve this problem.I am primarily stuck with proving that $Ker(\varphi)=\{0\}$ because $f(X)\in Ker(\varphi)$ means that $f(X)\in \langle F\rangle$ but form there how can I show that $f(X)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(X)\in \langle F\rangle$ i.e. if $f(X)=FG$ for some $G\in k[X,Y],$ prove by contradiction that $G=0.$ For this, reason on the $Y$-degree of $f,F,G.$

Comment: Thanks! It helped me.Suppose $f(X)=F(X,Y).G(X,Y)$ then look at the equation in $k[X][Y]$ where the RHS is independent of $Y$ and $F$ contains a monic $Y^n$ term and if $G(X,Y)$ is non-zero ,then it will generate some $b(X)Y^m$ where $m\geq n$ in the product and comparing coefficients we arrive at a contradiction.